# Como pegar valor de um SQL em php?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial=$pdo->prepare('SELECT SUM(valor) AS vTotal FROM saldo
                                                                                    WHERE data=:data
                                                                                    AND empresa_idempresa=:id_empresa');

$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('id_empresa', $id_empresa);
$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('data', $data);
$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->execute();

while ($linha=$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $valorTotalSaldoInicial = $linha['vTotal'];

}
echo $valorTotalSaldoInicial." - ";
?>
```

Como faço pra pegar o vTotal do SQl e inserir em uma variável PHP?

Comment: Dá algum erro? sempre retorna mais de um registro?

Comment: Não, mas aparece um valor errado. Ao invés de aparecer 600, aparece 300.

Comment: Mas a ideia é retornar só um registro ou não? pq caso tenha mais registros `$valorTotalSaldoInicial` vai ter sempre o último valor do loop. Se executar a consulta direto no banco o resultado vem correto?

Comment: A ideia é retornar o valor vTotal!

Comment: @rray, veja como está o comando SQL, eu faço um somar valores e crio uma alias! Então, a soma está no alias, correto?

Comment: Sim isso está correto.

Comment: Sim, já tentei e vem correto se dou esse comando no SQL.

Comment: Então, eu preciso pegar esse alias com o php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo, estou levando em consideração que sua conexão ao banco de dados esteja correta.

Não haveria necessidade desse laço While.

```
<?php
     $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial=$pdo->prepare('SELECT SUM(valor) AS vTotal 
     FROM saldo WHERE data=:data  AND  empresa_idempresa=:id_empresa');
?>
```

No SQL acima você utiliza o comando **SUM** do sql que irá somar todos os resultados encontrados em sua querie, portanto essa querie só ira retornar uma linha. Se tivesse utilizado a cláusula **GROUP BY**, teria que usar um laço de repetição porque dependendo do campo utilizado no agrupamento poderia responder  mais de uma linha, e nesse caso usamos o laço para percorrer as N linhas respondidas.

No código abaixo podemos então depurar o retorno do banco, visualizando melhor o que pode estar acontecendo, utilize, print_r() como abaixo:

```
<?php
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial=$pdo->prepare('SELECT SUM(valor) AS vTotal 
    FROM saldo WHERE data=:data AND empresa_idempresa=:id_empresa');

    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('id_empresa', $id_empresa);
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('data', $data);
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->execute();

    $linha = $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Utilize a tag PRE do HTML para manter a formatação no navegador.
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($linha); echo "</pre>"; exit;

    $valorTotalSaldoInicial = $linha['vTotal'];
    echo $valorTotalSaldoInicial." - ";
?>
```

Se na impressão da depuração continuar a vir 300 ao invés de 600 como comentado, então existe algum erro nos registros salvos no seu banco de dados. Nesse caso remova o **SUM** da querie e mande imprimir todos os resultados na página dessa forma:

```
<?php
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial=$pdo->prepare('SELECT valor AS vTotal 
    FROM saldo WHERE data=:data AND empresa_idempresa=:id_empresa');

    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('id_empresa', $id_empresa);
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->bindValue('data', $data);
    $buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->execute();

    while ($linha=$buscaValorTotalSaldoInicial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      //Utilize a tag PRE do HTML para mantes a formatação no navegador.
      echo "<pre>"; print_r($linha); echo "</pre>"; exit;
    }
?>
```

Analise os valores impressos manualmente para encontrar o erro, compare com os registros no próprio banco de dados e verifique se os filtros definidos na clausula **WHERE** estão corretos! E se precisar altere sua pergunta com os resultados e poste aqui.